# How to add a command to the zsh history from python

Tags: python, zsh

I am writing a shell wrapper script ([term-cheat](https://github.com/select/term-cheat)) in python that can be used to find, collect and execute shell commands. I would love to add the executed commands to the shell history.
I tried several things like the following but did not succeed.

```
subprocess.Popen(['zsh', '-ic', 'print -s "$1"', '_', command_string])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the executed command to the corresponding history file in the home folder of the executing user.

For bash it should be ~/.bash_history zsh may uses another file, but it should also be in the home directory.